# Android button does not print out a string message

Tags: java, android

I have tried to search in android developers but I had no luck.

My onClick method does not print any message. I want to change my text from ... to ...; however nothing happens when I click it.

JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the Cookie button is clicked.
     */
    public void eatCookie(View view) {
        display("I'm so full");
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(String status) {
        TextView statusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.status_text_view);
        statusTextView.setText("" + status);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B388FF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/android_cookie_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/before_cookie" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="I'm so hungry"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="EAT COOKIE"
        android:onClick="eatCookie"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is "I'm so hungry" displaying before the button click ?

Comment: The exact code is working fine for me try cleaning the project and then re run the project

Comment: How can i "clean" the project, it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Build -> Clean Project and then run the code

Comment: That made it work! Thanks! xD

Comment: Cool happy to help accept and upvote my answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working correct in my device
Try to Clean your project and re run the code again.

**Build** -> **Clean**

and then run the code